# Understanding nested Monad constraints

Tags: haskell, io, monads, transformation, monad-transformers

Say I have the following type:

```
data Row = Row
  { 
    id                          :: !AddressID
  }
```

with the following internal transformation function:

```
makeAddress :: MonadIO m => MonadError Error m => Connection -> Row -> m Address
makeAddress _ Row{..} = return $ Address "Potato"
```

I then have the following function to read from a database using [Postgres.Simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6.2/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html):

```
findMany
  :: MonadIO m
  => MonadReader Context m
  => MonadError Error m
  => [AddressID]
  -> m [Address]

findMany ids = do
  db <- view Context.db
  xs <- liftIO $ PG.query db sql_query_addr $ PG.Only (PG.In (map unAddressId ids))
  if (length xs) == (length ids)
    then do
      let addresses = concat (map (makeAddress db) xs)
      return addresses
    else
      throwError $ AddressNotFound Nothing

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sql_query_addr :: PG.Query
sql_query_addr = [qms|
  SELECT *
  FROM addresses a
  WHERE a.id in ?
|]
```

This fails to compile with:

```
    • Could not deduce (MonadIO [])
        arising from a use of ‘makeAddress’
      from the context: (MonadIO m, MonadReader Context m,
                         MonadError Error m)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   findMany :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                               (MonadIO m, MonadReader Context m, MonadError Error m) =>
                               [AddressID] -> m [Address]
        at app/Impl/ReadModelApi/FindMany.hs:(22,1)-(27,18)
    • In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(makeAddress db)’
      In the first argument of ‘concat’, namely
        ‘(map (makeAddress db) xs)’
      In the expression: concat (map (makeAddress db) xs)
   |
34 |       let quotations = concat (map (makeAddress db) xs)
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I realize that my `makeAddress` function is needlessly complex, this is a minimal case, boiled down from a much larger, more sideffecty transformation function.

But I don't understand why this fails to compile, I would have thought that:

Given this type: `makeAddress :: MonadIO m => MonadError Error m => Connection -> Row -> m Address`, the type of `makeAddress db` is `MonadIO m => MonadError Error m -> Row -> m Address`. Given `xs` has type `[Row]`, `map (makeAddress db) xs` should give `[Addresses]`.

And given that both the inner and outer `m` (in `makeAddress` and in `findMany`) is an instance of the `MonadIO` typeclass, these should be compatible monads?

Clearly this is incorrect, but I have no idea where my reasoning breaks down, or how to therefore fix my implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say:

```
makeAddress :: MonadIO m => MonadError Error m => Connection -> Row -> m Address
```

Sure. And:

```
makeAddress db :: MonadIO m => MonadError Error m -> Row -> m
```

Close enough. It's actually `m Address` at the end, but I assume this was just a typo. And:

```
map (makeAddress db) xs :: [Address]
```

This is your first mistake. You have lost the `m`! It is actually:

```
map (makeAddress db) xs :: MonadIO m => MonadError Error m => [m Address]
```

The explanation for the error is that we have

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

and so, for `[m Address]` to be equal to `[[a]]`, we must choose `m ~ []` and `a ~ Address`¹; but then `[]` is not a monad that can do IO, so the `MonadIO m` constraint isn't satisfied. Whoops!

Instead of `concat`, you can use `sequenceA`:

```
sequenceA :: Applicative m => [m a] -> m [a]
-- OR, specializing,
sequenceA :: MonadIO m => MonadError m => [m Address] -> m [Address]
```

This `map`-`sequenceA` combo is so common, it has its own name:

```
traverse :: Applicative m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

¹ If you haven't seen `~` before, you may replace it with `=` everywhere in this answer and nothing of importance will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

`concat (map f list)` requires `f` to return a list. This is so `map f list` can produce a list-of-lists to `concat`.

Hence, in your code you are using `makeAddress` choosing `m = []` so that `map (makeAddress ...) xs :: [[Address]]` and `concat (....) :: [Address]`. Now, `makeAddress` requires that the monad `m` is in class `MonadIO`, but `m = []` is not, hence the error.

Try using something like

```
...
then mapM (makeAddress db) xs
else ...
```